# Composition of sets with positive upper density

Tags: limsup-and-liminf

Let $A$ be a set of positive integers $\{a_n: n\ge 1\}$ (in increasing order) with positive upper density, that is,
$$
\limsup_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}|A \cap [1,n]|>0.
$$
Let also $B=\{b_n: n\ge 1\}$ a set of positive upper density.

Is it true that $\{a_{b_n}: n\ge 1\}$ has positive upper density?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Counterexample** based on my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1039164/natual-density-inside-a-subsequence).

The set
$$A=(1!,2!]\cup(4!,\ 5!]\cup(7!,\ 8!]\cup(10!,\ 11!]\cup(13!,\ 14!]\cup\cdots$$
has upper density $1$, since
$$\frac{|A\cap[1,\ (3n+2)!]|}{(3n+2)!}\ge\frac{(3n+2)!-(3n+1)!}{(3n+2)!}=\frac{3n+1}{3n+2}\to1.$$

The subset $S\subset A$ defined by
$$S=(4!,\ 4!+3!]\cup(7!,\ 7!+6!]\cup(10!,\ 10!+9!]\cup(13!,\ 13!+12!]\cup\cdots$$
has density $0,$ since
$$\frac{|S\cap[1,\ (3n+1)!+(3n)!]|}{(3n+1)!+(3n)!}=\frac{3!+6!+\cdots+(3n)!}{(3n+1)!+(3n)!}\lt\frac2{3n+1}\to0.$$

However, $S$ has upper density $1$ in $A,$ since
$$\frac{|S\cap[1,\ (3n+1)!+(3n)!|}{|A\cap[1,\ (3n+1)!+(3n)!|}\ge\frac{(3n)!}{(3n-1)!+(3n)!}=\frac{3n}{3n+1}\to1.$$

I hope this is good enough. If you insist on putting it in your awful $a_n,b_n,a_{b_n}$ notation, I'm afraid it's going to get ugly.

Comment: This is perfect. The curious thing is that it works under the (a bit stronger) assumption the *lower* density of $B$ is positive

Comment: I wouldn't say positive lower density is **a bit** stronger that positive upper density, I'd say it's **a lot** stronger.

Comment: I know, I know :P In that case, taking a suitable subset of $B$, it can be assumed without loss of generality that $B$ admits positive density

Comment: @Nduccio Wait a minute. Are you saying that, if $B$ has positive lower density, then there is a subset of $B$ whose density exists and is positive? Are you sure about that?

Comment: @Nduccio In some old notes of mine I find the statement: for any given $\alpha\in[0,1)$ there is a subset $A$ of $\mathbb N,$ with lower density $\alpha$ and upper density $1,$ such that there is no subset of $A$ whose density exists and is positive.

Comment: You are right. There are two results about the Darboux property of upper and lower densities (at least, the ones which I know): every upper and lower density has the Darboux property (see here http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X17300033); and another one (which is related to your result) is the PhD thesis of Georges Grekos, about the *joint* Darboux property of the lower and upper *asymptotic* density, published in JNT here http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022314X78900343 .

Comment: In particular, the closed-convex subsets of $[0,1]^2$ (with the obvious constraints due to monotonicity) cover all the possibilities. Hence, your example has to exist :D